# Debugging PHP Cloud application via SSH tunnel

Tags: php, eclipse, ssh, cloud, zend-debugger

I'm trying to use remote debugging in Eclipse/Windows via an SSH tunnel as described in these articles on PHP Cloud.

- http://www.phpcloud.com/help/putty-ssh-debug-tunnel
- http://www.phpcloud.com/help/debugging-overview

I've been able to establish an SSH connection using PuTTY with public/private key managed by Pagent. I'm now facing issues when testing the debugger in Eclipse's Debug Configurations menu. I've set up a server with the following details.

- Base URL: http://lhith.my.phpcloud.com (the link to my application on
  PHP Cloud).
- Local web root: `C:\Users\Luke\workspace\lhith` (the path that contains
  index.php on my local copy)
- Path mapping: `/.apps/http/__default__/0/1.7-zdc` (the path containing
  index.php on the server) -> `/lhith` (path containing index.php in the
  workspace)
- File: `/lhith/index.php`
- URL: http://lhith.my.phpcloud.com

I also configured Zend Debugger to use port 10137 and the Client Host/IP of 127.0.0.1.
When I connect my SSH session and then try to test the debugger I see the error "A timeout occurred when the debug server attempted to connect to the following client hosts/IPs: -127.0.0.1"

What could be going wrong here? What can I do about it?

Thank you for any assistance provided.

Answer (score 2):

I made some progress on this tonight.  I setup port forwarding on my internet router to forward port 10137 to my computer and then added my internet routers public IP address to the list of allowed hosts on the Zend Server debug settings on my.phpcloud.com.

I also added this IP to the Debugger configuration in Eclipse and was able to successfully connect to the remote system.  It appears there is a problem with the SSH remote tunnel settings, I will keep digging but I wanted to share my findings so far as this has been driving me crazy!